# Problems with slash symbol

Tags: php, html

I created form, when i submit it, i made that it just go to the same form page. When i changed value of variable( to the m=files&a=addedit) it keeps creating new one / symbol. Here is the code, and bellow the code there is the link to the picture.

```
    $referrer = "m=files&a=addedit";
?>
<form name="uploadFrm" action="?m=files" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $referrer; ?>" />
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFmXo.jpg

What should i do to fix this from / creation.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: When i use fullpath it shows http://website.com/index.php?http:/website.com/index.php?m=files&a=addedit

Comment: @Huey TRYING TO STOP WEBSITE FROM CREATING MORE ///////

Comment: As in, what were you trying to do in the first place before you ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using full path (with `http`) should fix this issue. Try change the action attribute to:

```
action="http://www.your-domain.com?m=files"
```

Comment: I did this `<form name="uploadFrm" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>?m=files" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` And now it only create second / symbol, and not more not it loks like mysite.com//?m=files always //. How can i now stop it from creating second one?

Comment: @McLaren : Looks like you something wrong in your setup then. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` should not report that.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unusual to want to put a `?` in the URL in a form `action` attribute. I'm not sure why you're doing that.

I'd suggest replacing it with a hidden field for `m`:

```
<form name="uploadFrm" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="m" value="files" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $referrer; ?>" />
```

Try that, and let us know if it works.

If you still have problems, then it's likely that the issue is actually somewhere else, not in the HTML form code you've given.

Possible places you should look:

- A badly configured mod_rewrite can be prone to doing this kind of thing.
- The input field on the form is called `redirect`; maybe the problem is happening when you do the redirect?

Comment: When i make it . dot. I get hard error. So i made this `<form name="uploadFrm" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>?m=files" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` And now it create max 2 - / but not more. What can i do to stop creating that second one

Comment: I still think there's a problem with a mod_rewrite, or something like that in your server config. The reason you're not getting any more than two slashes now is because the fully-qualified URL is forcing it back. It's still generating one extra slash, which will be your initial redirect causing problems with mod_rewrite, but it can't make any additional ones because you've given it an absolute URL.